# How do I load an image file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have to use Matlab to read a picture and make a joint histogram and I'm new to Matlab.  When I try to read the Image by using `imread` function it does not work.

```
h= imread('a.tif');
??? Error using ==> imread at 363
File "a.tif" does not exist.
```

Can anyone help me figure out this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnot work?" Error message? And what have you tried related to doing a joint histogram?

Comment: Some code would be nice, could you post what you have so far?

Answer (score 7):

One easy way to make sure you have the right path and file name is [uigetfile](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/uigetfile.html).

To determine your path and filename, use

```
 [filename,path]=uigetfile();
```

Then modify the code you have written to include the path as well. (If you're new to MATLAB, the syntax for combining two string arrays is `[str1, str2]`)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a.tif doesn't exist, or is located in the wrong directory ?

Since you didn't specify a path to the file then it needs to be in MATLAB's working directory (probably the same directory as where your .m file resides). Alternatively you can just specify a full (absolute) path to the .tif file.

Comment: how can I fix this problem ,PLZ

Comment: Check that (a) file a.tif exists and (b) that it is located in the correct directory.

Comment: I saved a.tif in the disk top

Comment: Since you didn't specify a path to the file then it needs to be in MATLAB's working directory (probably the same directory as where your .m file resides). Alternatively you can just specify a full (absolute) path to the .tif file.

Comment: you can navigate to the correct directory using the usual `cd 'path/to/dir'`, also you can check the current directory using `pwd`

Comment: imread should be able to find the file 'a.tif' anywhere in your Matlab path. If the file is located under 'C:\', use "addpath('C:\')" on the Matlab console before running your code

Comment: You should put your image in work directory! or put your path instead

Comment: May be the MATLAB itself just doesn't support the picture with pixels larger than some value.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't exist mean this image isn't supported by Matlab library 
So, you should browse an image from your files but you must write URL FOR the Image like this :

```
a= (' D:\images\Angry Birds\bird.jpg');
imshow(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the picture first go to workspace then import data and select your file